# Ruby - transform initialized array to normal array with numbers?

Tags: ruby, arrays

assuming i got this input .txt

```
10000, 150
345, 32
```

When i have initialized from an input file into a class like this:

```
class A
    def initialize(b,c)
    @b = b
    @c = c
    end
end

input = File.open("data", "r")
input.each do |line|
    l = line.split(',')
    arr << A.new(l[0], l[1])
end

p arr
```

i get this output [#A:0x00000002816440 @b="10000", @c=" 150">

how can i get it to an array like this

```
[[10000, 150][345, 32]]
```

Comment: Do you want the `class A` to have the string versions of the params, or is it part of exploring how to get the end result?

Comment: well i need to compare the input numbers with other numbers(int) alot of times in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `input.txt` contains the below data :

```
10000, 150
500, 10
8000, 171
45, 92
```

I can think of as below :

```
class A
  def initialize(b,c)
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end
  def attrs
    instance_variables.map{|var| instance_variable_get(var).to_i}
  end
end

input = File.open('/home/kirti/Ruby/input.txt', "r")
ary = input.each_with_object([]) do |line,arr|
  l = line.split(',')
  arr << A.new(*l).attrs
end

ary
# => [[10000, 150], [500, 10], [8000, 171], [45, 92]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Improvement suggested by Neil.

```
File.readlines("input.txt").map{|s| s.split(",").map(&:to_i)}
# => [[10000, 150], [345, 32]]
```

Comment: This is what to do if the `class A` is not relevant - i.e. the two-part arrays are the best representation of the data in the rest of the code. Except I'm not so sure about use of `split($/)` - why not just use `File#each_line`?

Comment: @NeilSlater Yeah, that may be better. I first wrote it where a string is given. I will rewrite it.

Comment: Somehow, `File.each_line` is not defined in Ruby 2.1. Maybe it has been deprecated.

Comment: I don't have 2.1 available to verify. Recall it's an instance method, so would be `File.open("input.txt").each_line` - so `File.readlines` is a better choice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do two things:

- Convert the string inputs to numbers
- Assuming you have further use for the `class A`, add a `.to_a` method to the class

You could do the first part in multiple places, but a simple thing to do is have the class sort out the conversion. Then the resulting code would look like this:

```
class A
  def initialize(b,c)
    @b = b.to_i
    @c = c.to_i
  end

  def to_a
    [ @b, @c ]
  end
end

input = File.open("data", "r")
input.each do |line|
    l = line.split(',')
    arr << A.new(l[0], l[1]).to_a
end

p arr
```